# WiFi is automatically disabled on sleep/suspend (WiFi is disabled with hardware switch) Intel wireless AC 3165

Tags: networking, drivers, 19.10

My laptop is HP Pavillion and it has Intel Wireless 3165 chip.

Tried downloading firmware from intel and putting in /lib/firmware

Additional Drivers does not allow to select other options.

[image: Software and Updated Additional Drivers]

[image: sudo lshw -C network]

will provide further info if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **System** > **Preferences** > **Power Management**. Check the setting next to **When laptop lid is closed** By default, It will be set to `Suspend`, which turns off most of your computer's parts except the memory (RAM) to save power, including the wireless card. Change it to Blank screen, then it won't do that.

Note that there are separate settings for when it's plugged into the wall and when it's on battery that you can select from the top. You'll need to change it for both. 
Also, make sure that the `Connect automatically` box is checked in your wireless connection setting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what I wanted was to solve the problem on the computer suspend.

Comment: Edited question if that was confusing.

Comment: How can I boost this question?